# Visual Studio for Mac Data_app not found?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac

I am new to MVC web development! 
I am using visual studio for Mac and is trying to build a login and registration page for my web. However, I can't find the Data_app folder. A lot of the online searches say that I can just create those folder myself, however, when I try to add files (for the app_data), I couldn't find it in the visual studio. Can I just manually create those too? or this just wouldn't work on a mac?

Comment: What kind of project did you create?

Comment: @LexLi I am creating a web application MVC

Comment: Please state the exact name in Visual Studio template, and the category https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/create-new-projects?view=vsmac-2019#creating-a-new-project-from-a-template Keep in mind that nobody can see your screen.

Comment: @LexLi It is the .NET Core -> App -> ASP .NET Core (Web Application (Model-View-Controller).

Comment: Then clearly you have read posts like https://edi.wang/post/2018/10/31/migrating-old-aspnet-applications-to-net-core You do need to manually create that folder and also manually add any data file you would like to include (or create those files if they don't ever exist). In general ASP.NET Core suggests you use its Identity feature to develop login pages, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio You should neglect any posts on old ASP.NET as they don't apply to .NET Core.